# Several makeindex in TeXnicCenter

Tags: indexing, subdividing, texniccenter

I have a problem relating to using `\makeindex` in TeXnicCenter. I use different indexes (such as `\makeindex{name}` and `\makeindex{place}`), but TeXnicCenter gives a warning asking for nameoftexfile.idx. This file should not exist, but the files name.idx and place.idx seems to be made the way they should.

What "Command line arguments to pass to MakeIndex" should I use in the build setting when I have several named indexes?

Comment: It is more important where the files are than how many.  Try Build=>Define Output Profiles=>Wizard and store your files anywhere in the makeindex folder (you can create a new subfolder for you own files).

Comment: I use this on TeXstudio: `"/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/makeindex" ?*.idx`.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I currently have the "Path to MakeIndex executable:" as C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\makeindex.exe. The idx-files are generated in the same folder as my tex-file.

Comment: If I name one of the indexes the same as my tex-file the index is printed as it shall. I can also get TeXnixCenter to process other idx.files by stating the name in the arguments passed to MakeIndex, but it is then merged and sorted with the index with the same name as the tex-file. For some reason it will not print two indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is---if I understand your question right---that you need to process more than one index file.

The general way in your case is (let's say you code is in file `mwe.tex`):

1. run `pdflatex mwe.tex`.  No check the directory of this file.  There you will find several files `*.idx`, depending on your code you did not show us.
2. Now you have to run `makeindex` with each of the created `idx` files.  To do that in one run write an batch file and add there all `makeindex` runs you need.
3. In the relevant TeXniccenter output profile add the batch file `mybatch.bat` into the postprocessor.  Then, if you compile your `mwe.tex` file is the batch file automatic run afterwards, so that with the next compile run(s) you will see the resulting indices in your document.

Example for the batch file `mybatch.bat`:

```
@echo off
makeindex name.idx -t name.ilg -o name.ind -s nomencl.ist
makeindex place.idx -t place-ilg -o place.ind -s nomencl.ist
```

Add more lines if needed. Change the names `name` and `place` as needed.  If you have an own index style or several styles change `-s nomencl.ist` to the right style file name.

If you show us a complete MWE I can show you the screenshots for the configuration you need for TeXnicCenter 2.0 stable.

Comment: If I execute the commands using a script or typing in a command window I get it right, but for some reason running it through TeXnicCenter fails.